# Changes to entry creation in 2.7.0?

Tags: 2.7.0

I've upgraded to EE 2.7.0 from 2.5.5. I've now noticed a change in how form submissions are handled. In the past I could make a channel entry and then go back with the back button and save that entry again for a new post. This was very useful when making a lot of similar entries. However, this no longer works. If I go back after submitting an entry and then try resaving it, I am redirected to the CP home page.

Is this an intended change and if so is there any way to get back the previous behaviour, via add-ons or settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [Secure Forms](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/security_settings.html#process-form-data-in-secure-mode) feature doing its job - it's been around for a long time, but perhaps it has gotten more strict as of late.

You can disable it if it's really important to continue this workflow you've been using, but it will do so site-wide, and for front-end form submissions as well, just so you're aware.